# React-router-dom rendering component on the same page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am using react-router-dom in my project when i am proving routes instead of rendering the component in another page dom rendering component in the same page below my first component 
My App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css'
import  Layout from './components/front/layout'
import FirstPage from './components/index/firstpage';
import {BrowserRouter ,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
render(){
return (  
<div className="container">
<BrowserRouter>
<FirstPage/>
<Switch>
<Route path='/Layout' exact component={Layout} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
</div> 
);
}
}
export default App;
```

My another middlePortion.js where i am using  imported from react-router-dom to route to another page

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Button, Form } from 'reactstrap';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import '../../css/style.css'
 import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
 class Middleportion extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.Submit = this.Submit.bind(this);
 }
 render() {
 const layStyle={
   color:'white'
  };
  return (
 <div className='row frnt'>
 <div className="col-md-3">
 </div>
 <div className="col-md-6 am ">
 <div className="row align-items-center">
 <div className="row justify-content-center bg-primary  pp">
 <ul className="list-unstyled">
 <li><Link style={layStyle} to='/Layout'>
      male
    </Link></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div className="col-md-3">
 </div>
    </div>
 );
 }
 }
 export default Middleportion;
```

I want to render my Layout component on separate page but its rendering on the same page please help me out

Comment: I'm a little confused with the context of the problem. Is the problem that FirstPage and Layout are both rendering on the '/Layout' route?

Comment: yes on /Layout route both FirstPage and Layout are rendering.Layout is rendering just after FrontPage component i guess i should use conditional routing  but still can anyone help me

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you're rendering `FirstPage` manually as if to be hard coded.
In order to get `FirstPage` and `Layout` to render in separate routes, you need to create a separate route inside your `<Switch>` and use `FirstPage` as the `component` prop like you did with `Layout`.
It would look like this:

```
(
  <div className="container">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={FirstPage} />
        <Route exact path='/Layout' component={Layout} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
)
```

With the setup above, the `FirstPage` component would render only on the `/` route and the `Layout` component would only render on the `/layout` route.